# How to use Huawei adskit in react native?

Tags: ads, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ads

I want to implement ads Kit in React Native.
How to add AdsKit into my React Native App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, HMS Core does not provide an Ads SDK for ReactNative officially. Hence, it is necessary for you to develop your own RN Bridge for Ads Kit.

There is a nice repo out here, implementing custom RN Bridges for HMS Account, Push and Analytics Kit -Ads might be lil bit tricky though-. It can be reference for you.
https://github.com/onurkenis/reactnative-hms-birdge

Here is the link for Ads SDK of HMS Core
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/ads-sdk-introduction

Answer (score 0):

HUAWEI Ads Kit provides [an integration guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/introduction-0000001050196714-V1) for React Native apps, and it is  available on the HUAWEI Developers website.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your comment. I will be waiting until they release.

Comment: @KonSmart I update the link to the integration guide.

Answer (score 0):

Cross platform support is added, You can check the [documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050196714) as well.

In three steps you can integrate it.

Step 1: Create project in [AppGallery](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201286157525130049&fid=0101188387844930001)

Step 2: Add react native [plugin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/integrating-sdk-0000001050201941)

Step 3: Choose an add type and start the client development,
As of now 5 different types of ads are supported by Ads Kit,

- [Banner Ads](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/banner-0000001050439147)
- [Interstitial Ads](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/interstitial-0000001050198935)
- [Splash Ads](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/splash-0000001050439151)
- [Native Ads](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/native-0000001050316236)
- [Rewarded Ads](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/reward-0000001050196920)

After selecting the add type, complete the integration.